# Ulam Spiral (for diagonal numbers) writing program python

Tags: python

I am writing a code the represent the Ulam Spiral Diagonal Numbers and this is the code I typed myself

```
t = 1
i = 2
H = [1]


while i < 25691 :
    for n in range(4):
        t += i
        H.append(t)
    i += 2
print(H)
```

The number "25691" in the code is the side lenght of the spiral.If it was 7 then the spiral would contain 49 numbers etc.

Here H will give you the all numbers in diagonal. But I wonder is there a much faster way to do this.

For example if I increase the side lenght large amount it really takes forever to calculate the next H.

Code Example:

```
t = 1
i = 2
H = [1]

for j in range(25000,26000):
    while i < j :
        for n in range(4):
            t += i
        H.append(t)
    i += 2
```

For example my computer cannot calculate it so, is there a faster way to do this ?

Comment: Are you writing this in Python3 or Python2?

Comment: I am writing in python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to calculate the intermediate values:

> Diagonal, horizontal, and vertical lines in the number spiral correspond to polynomials of the form
>
> [image]
>
> where b and c are integer constants.

[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral#Explanation)

You can find b and c by solving a linear system of equations for two numbers.

```
17 16 15 14 13
18  5  4  3 12 ..
19  6  1  2 11 28
20  7  8  9 10 27
21 22 23 24 25 26
```

Eg for the line *1,2,11,28* etc:

> f(0) = 4*0*0+0*b+c = *1* => **c = 1**
>
> f(1) = 4*1*1+1*b+**1** = *2* => 5+b = 2 => **b = -3**
>
> f(2) = 4*2*2+2*(**-3**)+**1** = *11*
>
> f(3) = 4*3*3+3*(**-3**)+**1** = *28*